# Parse Modified Date & Time

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script use to display a list of files's modified date & time.

This is the script's code :

```
for %%v in (*.html) do ( 
    echo %%~tv
)
```

Question is, how do I parse the result into two variables. Each for date and time consecutively.

Please advice.

Regards,

Dino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to solve such a problem for myself, I would do the following:

1. I would run that script of yours to see what output it produces. To be honest, I *have* run that script, and here's what I've got:

   ```
   12/15/2009 08:54 AM
   12/15/2009 09:30 AM
   05/31/2011 07:35 PM
   12/02/2009 05:53 PM
   12/19/2009 09:33 PM
   04/10/2010 02:07 PM
   11/23/2010 03:21 PM
   01/06/2010 12:03 PM
   ```
2. My next step then would be to determine (visually) what part of every string is the date and what part is the time, I mean, what position the substrings start at and what their lengths are.

   In my case it appears to be... (where's my ruler?)

   ```
             1    1
   0    5    0    5    
   ||||||||||||||||||||
   04/10/2010 02:07 PM
   ```

   Ah yes, position 0, length 10 for the date and position 11, length 8 for the time. (As you can see, for strings in batch scripts I have a special ruler that starts from 0.)
3. Now that I know where to locate the date and the time in the output, I can extract them accordingly. But first I'd need a variable for the whole string, because extracting is applied to environment variables, not loop variables. Here:

   ```
   SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
   FOR %%v IN (*.html) DO ( 
     SET datetime=%%~tv
     ECHO !datetime:~0,10!
     ECHO !datetime:~11,8!
   )
   ENDLOCAL
   ```

   You might have noticed that apart from introducing a variable I also added enabling delayed expansion (of variables). This is necessary, because with the immediate expansion, i.e. like this:

   ```
   FOR %%v IN (*.html) DO ( 
     SET datetime=%%~tv
     ECHO %datetime:~0,10%
     ECHO %datetime:~11,8%
   )
   ```

   it **wouldn't work**. The thing is, the `%datetime:…%` expressions would be evaluated *before* the loop was invoked, and thus would produce empty strings. (This peculiarity of behaviour applies to all cases where you have a bunch of commands in parentheses, whether it is a `FOR` loop, an `IF` or `IF..ELSE` command, or even simply a redirection applied to a set of commands, like `>file (commands)`.)

   Instead of just outputting the values you could store them in other variables to process later in the loop body:

   ```
   SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
   FOR %%v IN (*.html) DO ( 
     SET datetime=%%~tv
     SET fdate=!datetime:~0,10!
     SET ftime=!datetime:~11,8!
     :: now do whatever you like with !fdate! and !ftime!
     …
   )
   ENDLOCAL
   ```

Comment: Hi Andiy, great answer and explanation. Only some revision to last note, I'm using !fdate! and !ftime! instead of %fdate% and %ftime%. Many thanks ! Dino.

Comment: @Dino: Good catch, updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for mentioning it.