# batch file : user input manipulation

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch that that ask for some information  so I decided to use the command set /p "var=" , but I want to do some manipulation or limitation so firstly

1. if I want to ask for date `set /p "DATE=insert date like this 2012/07/15="` , I want to accept the answer only if the input was in this way 2012/07/15

2.if I want to ask for coupon number `set /p "NUMBER=insert number="` , I want to do IF THE CODE FIRST CHARACTER WAS Z THEN NUMBER=NUMBER IGNORING Z , example if the user insert z12345
i want NUMBER=12345 , so I did this half of the command `IF '%var:~0,1%'=='z' then ???`
so I dont know how to do the rest

also I noticed that if I want to do the 4th charcetr this wont work `IF '%var:~4,1%'=='g'`, why ?

Comment: Note that there's a system environment variable called `DATE`, which, unless overridden, evaluates to the current system date.

Comment: how i should use it in this case ?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use it, as I'm not sure what is the date your script is requesting. Anyway, the system's DATE variable value is seldom useful for something other than just *displaying* the current date. I could elaborate more with regard to why but my point was merely that if you use a name that has already been reserved by the OS for something else, you may encounter some "funny" behaviour working with such a variable. In particular, you cannot really undefine such a variable, because as soon as you do so, the system defines it back with a value the variable is intended to hold.

Comment: edit , if i do, SET /p "DATE=INSERT DATE (linke 2011/04/14)=" , can I insert 3 variables like var1/var2/var3 so i can use them to manipulate them later ?

Comment: Sorry, I think you've lost me there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `findstr /R` to check the input with a regular expression.

Something like

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "myDate="
set /p myDate=
if defined myDate (
  echo !myDate! | findstr /R "^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]/[0123456789][0123456789]/[0123456789][0123456789]" >nul && Echo ok || echo fail
)
```

Comment: great answer , but what about my second question ?

Comment: by the way , if i want to insert letters should i do [abc..to infinity] ? what about case insensitivity ?

Comment: As far as I can understand, the condition in `if defined date` can *never* be false, because `date` can never be undefined in Windows.

Comment: @Andriy M - Good point! Bad idea to use `date` asw variable name here, I will change it

Comment: @Leo92 - `but what about my second question?` Hmm, I show you the right direction, now you should be able to solve it your own

Comment: I just dont understand the ~0,1 thing

Comment: @Leo92: However, you could first try searching for an answer among existing questions. [Here's something you could start from.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235470/parse-modified-date-time "Parse Modified Date & Time") (I'm not claiming it's the best thing there is, but hopefully it should give you an idea.)

Comment: @AndriyM I just want to say that from your link i learned a powerful tool  that will solve a lot of my problems , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

At [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428) a way to write your own "SET /P" routine is explained, so you may modify it to suit your specific needs. Note that this is NOT a test after the string was read, but an interactive testing that is active while the string is being read. You may even limit the time the user have to complete the input!

Seek for "3- **GetKey.exe.hex**" auxiliary program and then for "Readline subroutine".

I hope it helps.

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

The following script shows how you can do both these tasks:

```
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off

    set /p "dt=Enter date as yyyy/mm/dd: "
    set rc=1
    echo x%dt%x| findstr /r "^x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]x$" >nul: && set rc=0
    if %rc%==1 (
        echo Invalid date
        goto :endl
    )
    echo Date was %dt%

    set /p "num=Enter number as z99999 or 99999: "
    if %num:~0,1%==xz set num=!num:~1!
    echo Number was %num%

:endl
    endlocal
```

The first section shows how you can use `findstr` with its regular expression capabilities to set an `rc` return code variable which can then be checked.

The second section shows how to strip off the first charcater from a string if it is `z`, although you may well find that `findstr` may be useful there as well so you can check the entire string, something like:

```
    set /p "num=Enter number as z99999 or 99999: "
    if %num:~0,1%==xz set num=!num:~1!
    set rc=1
    echo x%num%x| findstr /r "^x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]x$" >nul: && set rc=0
    if %rc%==1 (
        echo Invalid number
        goto :endl
    )
    echo Number was %num%
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work , the first half if i insert 123124/345345345/34234 it will be accepted , the second one if i insert z12432 it will print z12342 instead of 12342

Comment: @Leo92: Try again, I'd accidentally left off a `%` character while transcribing it.

Comment: for the first half , it work but still the second wont take off the z if i insert z12432 it will print z12342 instead of 12342

Comment: @Leo92 - You used a substring to test the 1st character, so use a substring to keep the remaining characters. Use `HELP SET` or `SET /?` from the command line to get all the options for substrings. Hint - the length does not need to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ReadFormattedLine subroutine for all kind of formatted input. For example, the command below read a line with date format; the slashes are automatically inserted as the user types the characters:

```
call :ReadFormattedLine myDate="####/##/##" /M "insert date like this 2012/07/15: "
```

The command below read a number comprised of 5 digits; the subroutine does not accept characters that are not digits:

```
call :ReadFormattedLine NUMBER="#####" /M "insert number: "
```

This subroutine is written in pure Batch so it does not require any additional program, and it allows several formatted input operations, like read passwords. You may download it from [Read a line with specific format](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5775).